# How to extract word after pattern matching

Tags: text-processing

input.txt

```
abc1 abc2 {"request":{"jjj":"opt1"},"user":{"name":"abc5"}}
xyz1 xyz2 {"request":{"xyz3":{"xyz4":{"xyz5":"xyz6"}},"jjj":"opt2"}}
ghi1 ghi2 {"request":{"ghi3":{"ghi4":{"ghi5":"ghi6"}},"jjj":"opt3"},"user":{"ghi7":"value"}}
```

need output like first two fields and word after matching string `jjj`

```
abc1 abc2 opt1
xyz1 xyz2 opt2
aaa1 aaa2 opt3
```

Comment: Also, you have to clarify if there are lines with no `jjj`, what is the output then? Print 2 fields or ignore the line?

Comment: First comment : Yeah, i.e typo,consider it jjj in double quotes,    
second comment : it has further nesting also.    
Third comment: There are no lines with out jjj

Comment: Please update your question with these details (not in comments). Also clarify if there can be blanks in the last part, inside `{}` (remove the dots, make the sample believable)

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: What format are the first two columns in? If I delete the first tab-delimited fields, will I be left with a clean JSON document that could potentially be parsed with a JSON parser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to using `sed`, you can use regex to extract necessary part from the third column while leaving the rest intact.

```bsh
sed 's/{.*"jjj":"\([^"]*\).*$/\1/g' input.txt
```

where my `input.txt` file contains:

```
abc1 abc2 {"abc3":{"jjj":"opt1"}}
xyz1 xyz2 {"xyz3":{"jjj":"opt2"}}
aaa1 aaa2 {"aaa3":{"aaa4:"jjkk"},.....{"jjj":"opt3"}}
```

Here, I'm trying to capture the value present in double-quotes after `"jjj":"` and before the next closing double-quote.

Comment: Thaks @Amit Singh.

Comment: @SrikanthRao Feel free to accept the answer which you think has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
{
  print $1, $2, \
   substr($0, 8+match($0, /\{"jjj":"[^"]+"/), RLENGTH-9)
}' input.txt
abc1 abc2 opt1
xyz1 xyz2 opt2
aaa1 aaa2 opt3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your third field appears to be valid JSON, you could consider something like this with `jq`:

```
$ awk -v cmd='jq -r ".. | .jjj? // empty"' '
  {printf "%s%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2,OFS; print $3 | cmd; close(cmd)}
' file
abc1 abc2 opt1
xyz1 xyz2 opt2
ghi1 ghi2 opt3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the three fields of the file are tab-delimited:

```
$ cut -f 3 file | jq -r '.request.jjj' | paste <( cut -f -2 file ) -
abc1    abc2    opt1
xyz1    xyz2    opt2
ghi1    ghi2    opt3
```

This extracts the JSON structures in the third field on each line and passes them to `jq` to extract the value of the `.request.jjj` key in each.  This data is then pasted back as the third column using `paste`.

If the data is delimited by single space characters:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 3- file | jq -r '.request.jjj' | paste -d ' ' <( cut -d ' ' -f -2 file ) -
abc1 abc2 opt1
xyz1 xyz2 opt2
ghi1 ghi2 opt3
```

Note that the first `cut` that extracts the JSON structures need to use `-f 3-` rather than just `-f 3` to make sure that no embedded space characters truncates the data.